# Ruby: Convert a bitarray to an integer

Tags: ruby, bitarray

I am trying to convert a bit array, such as `[0,0,1,0].to_i = 2` or `[0,1,0,1].to_i = 5`.

What possible ways are there to do this in Ruby?

Comment: What would you do to do the same the other way round? `input.to_s(2).each_char.map { |c| c == '1' }` isn't cutting it for huge numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
  [1] pry(main)> [0,0,1,0].join.to_i(2)
  => 2
  [2] pry(main)> [0,1,0,1].join.to_i(2)
  => 5
  [3] pry(main)>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly more sophisticated snippet (as compared to [Ryan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10770846)).

```
a1 = [0,0,1,0]
a2 = [0,1,0,1]

def convert a
  a.reverse.each.with_index.reduce(0) do |memo, (val, idx)|
    memo |= val << idx
  end
end

convert a1 # => 2
convert a2 # => 5
```

Comment: Question: does the usage of `.reverse` instead of `.reverse!` make a difference? If I understood correctly, the first one should consume double the memory, right

Comment: @Cadoiz `reverse!` mutates the original array. This has many consequences. One of which is if you convert the same array twice, you'll get different results. `convert(a1); convert(a1)`

Comment: @Cadoiz: but! instead of `reverse.each`, we can use `reverse_each` which does not build a temp array and does not touch the original array.

Comment: Especially the latter is great knowledge for me. It's unfortunately not there for my ancient linux, but [it definitely is for ruby >2.6.10](https://www.ruby-docs.org/v/2.6.10/Array/instance_method-reverse_each). I don't know how to find out earlier compatibility.